# How store data (documents) in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm studying mongodb and want to build a little database for web blogs page. 
It is known that in mongo we use collections and documents, in opposite, of tables and records.

I have 2 documents (entities): User (id, nikname) and Publication (id, title ...) In relational database we would have user_id as column inside "Publication" and this would mean that users able to have many publications.

**Example1**

```
User 
{
  id: "123456",
  nikname: "cool guy",
  publications: [   
        {
            id: "some id1",
            title: "some title111",
            text: "bla bla bla",
            // any fields
        },
        {
            id: "some id2",
            title: "some title222",
            text: "bla bla bla",
            // any fields
        },
        ....
    ]
}

Publication 
{
    id: "some id",
    title: "some title",
    text: "bla bla bla",
    // any fields       
}
```

In example above, each user has own array of publications.

**My question is:** Is this a good way to do like this? What if one user will have 1000 publications?

Moreover, if each user has an own publications then why we need to store publications table (in MONGO it is called COLLECTION)
outside the user as separate entity.

I was also thinking  about a storing publication ids inside of user.

**Example2**

```
User 
{
  id: "123456",
  nikname: "cool guy"
}

Publication 1
{
    id: "some id",
    title: "some title",
    text: "bla bla bla",
    // any fields   

    USER_ID: 123456 
} 

Publication 2
{
    id: "some id",
    title: "some title",
    text: "bla bla bla",
    // any fields

    USER_ID: 123456     
}
```

But **Example2** does not differ from relational approach...

So What way will be better ?

In short, would like to know opinions of guys who worked with mongo.

Comment: The first approach is the way to go. As you well said, the second example is a relational approach; it could be useful in some use-cases though. However, in your case, when you fetch a user, normaly, you will need her posts, too. So it's absolutely fine (and faster) to have the publications embedded in the user itself.

Comment: If using the first approach you are not storing the same data twice for 2 different user then first approach is the way to go. By that i meant if publications are not same for many a number of users then approach 1 is ok but if it is not like that then its always better to segregate the data as it would help you not to store same information twice, thrice or 'n' number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongo there are 3 ways you can design your model relationships.

- One to One
- One to Many (Embedded Docs) : your example 1
- One to Many (Document References) : your example 2

> Rule of thumb is that you need to consider your data retrieval pattern
>   of your application.

For example, if your application need to fetch Publication related to a particular user heavily, you can go for example 1 and you don't need to maintain publications in a separate collection (unless application requires it). Having a lot of sub documents are not a problem as far as a single document will not exceed the hard limits.

Example 2 of your one good if your application need to query by publications as well as user (similar to a relation model). However I see this is a not a optimized solution.

Some resource:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/

Comment: Thank you for response. I need to ponder about your answer a bit